# rdlc report works fine in VS but not on the client it deployed

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

My Report works fine on my own machine and in VS but I get this error "an error occurred during local report processing" on the client

Comment: Is there more to the error message? Does [this help](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/an-error-occurred-during-local-report-processing-in-rdlc)?

Comment: Are you using a SQL Server database.  The database query may not be finding the database.

Comment: This is the most generic error you can find working with rdlc. You have to catch the Exception and give a look at the various levels of InnerException; i.e.: ex.Message, ex.InnerException.Message, ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message